# Javascript Regex to match only a single occurrence no more or less

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below:

```
single-hyphen
```

I need to match the hyphen. However, I only want to match a single occurrence of the hyphen, no more or less.

So the string above will return true, but the two below will be false:

```
1. a-double-hyphen
2. nohyphen
```

How do I define a regex to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is it a requirement to have at least 1 other character before and at least 1 other character after the "-"? Or no, just the simple check for exactly "-" in the string? Like would "-asdf" or "asdf-" be valid?

Comment: If it's a requirement to have a character other than "-" at the beginning and end, then you could use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NmWTy/1/ - probably isn't most efficient, and doesn't use regex, but is just an option - that's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I was specifically looking for a regex which I found below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this

```
/^[^-]+-[^-]+$/
```

`^` depicts the start of the string

`$` depicts the end of the string

`[^-]+` matches 1 to many characters except `-`

Comment: Why `[^-]*?` and not `[^-]*`?

Comment: The reluctant matching is not useful and I'd use the `+` instead of the `*`. Better: `^[^-]+-[^-]+$`

Comment: @Tomalak: The `+` version will not match a case when the single hyphen is at the beginning or at the end of the string (`"-foo"`, `"foo-"`); yet they are strings with a single hyphen, and satisfy OP's requirements (unless OP misstated his objective).

Comment: Yeah, this works because I expect the hyphens to be between two characters as opposed to at ends, but @Amadan makes a good point. I think I'll use `/^[^-]*-[^-]*$/` for now though just to be sure.

Comment: @Amadan I was assuming a single hyphen at the start/end of the string should be invalid. The OP was not clear on this, though.

Comment: this didn't work for me, since it would match up to 3 characters. I needed to match only 1 character, so I had to use lookarounds: `(?<!-)-(?!-)`

Answer (score 8):

```
/^[^-]*-[^-]*$/
```

Beginning of string, any number of non-hyphens, a hyphen, any number of non-hyphens, end of string.

Comment: Java regular expressions do not use a delimiter character.

Comment: @Tomalak: JavaScript is not Java.

Answer (score 4):

Weird (and *not a Regex*)... but why not?

```
2 === str.split("-").length;
```

Comment: Lol...yeah, this is how Forrest Gump would have done it. I could probably have done it similar to what you have but I needed a regex.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh Well, in this case I would go for regex if and only if it is a *requirement*.

Comment: Yeah, it sort of was a requirement. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though. Just kiddin with the Forrest Gump reference too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
String.prototype.hasOne = function (character) {
    var first = this.indexOf(character);
    var last = this.lastIndexOf(character);

    return first !== -1 &&
        first === last;
};

'single-hyphen'.hasOne('-'); // true
'a-double-hyphen'.hasOne('-'); // first !== last, false
'nohyphen'.hasOne('-'); // first === -1, false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSF8T/

Answer (score 1):

Unconventional but it works. It doesn't manipulate the string or use regex.

```
 // only true if only one occurrence of - exists in string
 (str.indexOf("-") + 1) % ( str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1 ) === 0
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/egMP3/)