# Regular expression for matching single occurrence of ' (single quote) coming only between alphabets not on start or end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a string using regular expression in which single quote

1. **can appear zero or one time**
2. **should not be at the start or end of the string**
3. **should have at least one alphabet before it (if single quote appears)**

**Minimum length of the string should be 2 and maximum length should not exceed 25 characters**
**There can be maximum of two spaces**

I took some help from the following question on getting only a single occurrence of a character (in my case a single quote)

[Javascript Regex to match only a single occurrence no more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606905/javascript-regex-to-match-only-a-single-occurrence-no-more-or-less)

and came up with this

```
^([^']([a-zA-Z])+(\s){0,1})+('){0,1}([a-zA-Z][^'])+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/e3RSm4sqlp4Ijlz7)

Sample String that should get matched

- Shanon D'costa
- Shanon methews
- R C S
- J D'costa

Sample string that should not get matched

- ''Shanon Dcosta
- ''Shanon D'costa
- Shanon Dcosta (Space before Shanon or Space after Dcosta)
- Shanon Dcosta''
- shanon Lawrence james D'costa
- shanon 'costa

The problem:

1. My regEx matches string starting with space
2. It does **not match shanon d'cos and shanon d'costa** but matches shanon d'cost
3. Maximum of 25 character is also not working

Any help/advice regarding this would be appreciated.

EDIT 12-Sept-2013
The string should contain no special characters except single quote and space

Comment: It would be much much easier if you did not test all of the requirements in the same regex. Do you really need that?

Comment: Just use `str.length` to check the length of the string.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Bergi like Felix Kling pointed out I could seperate out the length checking.

Comment: @charanraj: You can separate out everything but simply using multiple regex then. I asked because sometimes there are problems where people can only use a single regex and not alter the code that applies it.

Comment: @Pointy no, it is not a homework problem. I was trying to implement a cleaner way to check for a valid name instead of if --else and checking indexOf etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check the conditions on their own:

```
/^(?=[a-z ']{2,25}$)(?=(?:\S+\s){0,2}\S*$)(?:[^']*|[^']*?[a-z]'[^']+)$/i
```

```
^                      # from start of string
(?=[a-z ']{2,25}$)     # 2 to 25 of the allowed chars until end of string
(?=(?:\S+\s){0,2}\S*$) # at most two spaces until end of string
(?:                    # either
 [^']*                 # no apostrophe
|                      # or
 [^']*?[a-z]'[^']+     # exactly one apostrophe preceded by alphabet letter
)$                     # to end of string
```

But they better be separated in code. So use

```
str.length >= 2 && str.length <= 25
 && /^(?:\S+\s){0,2}\S*$/.test(str)
 && /^[a-z ]*(?:[a-z]')?[a-z ]+$/i.test(str)
```

Comment: your answer is perfect. and thanks for providing such a good breakdown of the expression explaining it part by part.
But the regular expression allows " Shannon" with two spaces . I guess that is because of this part (?=\S*(?:\s\S*){0,2}$)

Comment: the string should not contain any special characters except single quote and space (added it now in the question). I replaced \S with [a-zA-Z] in the regular expression . ^(?=.{2,25}$)(?=[a-zA-Z]*(?:\s\S*){0,2}$)(?:[^']*|[^']*?[a-zA-Z]'[^']+)$
 If I keep \S in (?:\s\S*){0,2}$) the pattern matches for the input string Shanon %^Dcosta. And if I change the \S with [a-zA-Z] in (?:\s\S*){0,2}$) it does not matches Shanon D'costa

Comment: What's wrong with the two spaces, didn't you want to allow them? I've updated the post to reflect the limited character set.

Comment: The string could contain 2 spaces as in the example: R C S (space between R C and S), but the current expression allows you to start with space and then alphabets i.e <space><space>shanon. The string should not start with 2 spaces, maximum of spaces can appear in the string but not in the beginning. The changes you made fixed the problem I mentioned in the earlier comment

Comment: I've updated now so that the spaces must neither appear consecutively nor at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks @bergi. it is working fine now.
Also thanks for suggesting that instead of writing everything in a single regEx its better to break it in to chunks to reduce the complexity. Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-ahead to assert the quote usage and a simple repetition for the overall size:

```
^(?=([^']*[a-zA-Z]')?[^']+$).{2,25}$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/5wbCIY6AhS) working correctly with all examples given.