# Regex: How can I match just first one

Tags: regex, pcre

I tried like this "\<\%.*\%\>" in this site(https://www.debuggex.com/) but matched two string.
So, I want to match just first one thing in that below line. How can i do?

BLA BLA text text <%eval request("BLA")%> text text <%eval request("BLA")%> text BLA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to match? Can you give example input and output? Also, [does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606905/javascript-regex-to-match-only-a-single-occurrence-no-more-or-less)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (without global flag):

`<%.*?%>`

You can find the example here for PCRE: https://regex101.com/r/lcjAvZ/1