# Regex match string where symbol is not repeated

Tags: regex, string, repeat

I have like this strings:

`group items % together into%` **FALSE**

`characters % that can match any single` **TRUE**

How I can match sentences where symbol `%` is not repeated?

I tried like this pattern but it's found first match sentence with symbol `%`

`[%]{1}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606905/javascript-regex-to-match-only-a-single-occurrence-no-more-or-less

Comment: In addition: [`^[^%]*%[^%]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/3fO5V1/1/)

Comment: Is a sentence without any `%` a good match as well? e.g. `regex is cool.` ?

Comment: Yes it's good match @anubhava

Comment: ok then I think please make that requirement explicit in question to avoid getting wrong answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in python to return failure for lines that have more than one `%` in them:

```sh
^(?!([^%]*%){2}).+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMqu9b/1/)

`(?!([^%]*%){2})` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if `%` is found twice after line start.

Answer (score 0):

Just count them (Python):

```py
>>> s = 'blah % blah %'
>>> s.count('%') == 1
False
>>> s = 'blah % blah'
>>> s.count('%') == 1
True
```

With regex:

```py
>>> re.match('[^%]*%[^%]*$','gfdg%fdgfgfd%')
>>> re.match('[^%]*%[^%]*$','blah % blah % blah')
>>> re.match('[^%]*%[^%]*$','blah % blah blah')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='blah % blah blah'>
```

`re.match` must match from start of string, use `^` (match start of string) if using `re.search`, which can match in the middle of a string.

```py
>>> re.search('^[^%]*%[^%]*$','gfdg%fdgfgfd%')
>>> re.search('^[^%]*%[^%]*$','gfdg%fdgfgfd')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='gfdg%fdgfgfd'>
```

Comment: Your regex match this string with double `%` symbol and this incorrect result. String  `gfdg%fdgfgfd%`. Here is demo https://regex101.com/r/QYM9Xb/1

Comment: @AndreasHunter See edit. In Python `re.match` must match from the start of the string so it is correct. You didn't mention a language. Use `^[^%]%[^%]$` if whatever language you are using doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.search` as follows:

```py
items = ['group items % together into%', 'characters % that can match any single']
for item in items:
    output = item
    if re.search(r'^.*%.*%.*$', item):
        output = output + ' FALSE'
    else:
        output = output + ' TRUE'
    print(output)
```

This prints:

```
group items % together into% FALSE
characters % that can match any single TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "sentence" in your question is the same as a line in the input text. With that assumption, you can use the following:

`^[^%\r\n]*(%[^%\r\n]*)?$`

This, along with the multi-line and global flags, will match all lines in the input string that contain 0 or 1 '%' symbols.

`^` matches the start of a line
`[^%\r\n]*` matches 0 or more characters that are not '%' or a new line
`(...)?` matches 0 or 1 instance of the contents in parentheses
`%` matches '%' literally
`$` matches the end of a line