# Mongo regular expression no more then one dot in field

Tags: regex, mongodb

I need to select all records which contain no more than one dot in the field `name`.

For example:

`A.*` - include to select
`B.*` - include to select

`A.C.*` - exclude (2 dots)
`A.C.D.*` - exclude (3 dots)

All filtered strings always end with `.*` but I need select only records with one single dot.

```
@Query(value = """
        {
            "name" : {
                "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : .*\\.., "options" : ""}
            }
        }
        """)
Flux<Subject> findRoots();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Regex to match only a single occurrence no more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606905/javascript-regex-to-match-only-a-single-occurrence-no-more-or-less)

Comment: No, it's about javascript my question about MongoDB

Comment: The important part is the regex, which would still be valid for MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I know this core mongo Query but might be it's helpful to you.it's Working for me

```
 db.getCollection('test').find({data:{ "$regex": /^[a-z\d,]*\.?[a-z\d,]*$/ ,  $options :"i"} })
```

Comment: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader expected a string but found 'BsonRegularExpression{pattern='^[a-z\d,]*\.?[a-z\d,]*$', options=''}'.
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readStringFromExtendedJson(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:1410) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
 Suppressed: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a name but found ','.